# Python to return specific column using list comprehension or apply()

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert R code to Python code and stuck at this point. Can you tell me what is the best way to implement this code snippet in Python?

```
only0_0$count =0
for(i in 2:length(only0_0$ID))
{
    only0_0$count[i]=ifelse((only0_0$year[i]-1) %in% 
    clientData$Year[clientData$CUSTOMERID %in% only0_0$ID[i]],1,0)
}
```

Background:

1. Both clientData and only0_0 are DataFrames.
2. Client Data{columns: year, CustomerID, ...}
3. only0_0 {columns: year, ID}
4. ID and CustomerID both represents same thing and are not unique in the corresponding table.
5. Sort only0_0 by {'ID','year'}

PseudoCode:

1. In only0_0, create new column 'count' will all zeros.
2. for loop starting from second observation to last, populate 'count' variable as:

   - select all 'CustomerID' from clientData where 'ID' in only0_0 matches for a particular row.
   - e.g. only0_0.ID == 3197
   - clientData.CustomerID will return all rows id's with customerID=3197
   - e.g output of last step: rowid(or index in Python) {3,11, 81, 87}
   - extract corresponding year values from rows id's returned from last step
   - e.g. output of last step: {2006, 2008, 2009, 2006}
   - let's say: output of (only0_0.year - 1) == 2008
   - since 2008 is in {2006, 2008, 2009, 2006}, count = 1

Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: Can you turn it to psuedo code or rough C code? (doesn't need to run)  It is easy to give you a short python solution but it is quite hard to read `r` to this extent without experience in it.

Comment: Added Pseudo-code. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can you provide an example table (input and output) (some more user friendly variables names would be useful to but I could get by with input and output table).

Comment: Added example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `only0_0` and `clientData` are concretely, it is quite hard, but here are some snippets that should help you:

I assume `only0_0` is a `pandas.DataFrame` and `clientData` a dictionary, because it does not contain uniform data.

So e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
clientData = {'Year': [..., ...], 'CUSTOMERID_transformed': ....}
only0_0 = pd. DataFrame({'count': [1, 2, 3, ...], 'year': [2010, 2012, 2019, ...]})
```

```
only0_0.loc[i, 'count'] = 0
for i in range(1, only0_0.shape[0]):    # i.e. skipping the first row
   only0_0.loc[i, 'count'] = 0 if ... else 1
```

or

```
... = int(1-bool(...))
```

but I think it is more pythonic to write

```
if ...:
    only0_0.loc[i, 'count'] = 0
else:
    only0_0.loc[i, 'count'] = 1
```

Now for the condition, I think it is something composed of

```
(only0_0.loc[i, 'year'] - i) in clientData['Year'][...]
```

and

```
clientData['CUSTOMERID_transformed'] in only0_0.loc[i, 'ID0_0']
```

**EDIT:**
Your note suggests rather

```
only0_0.loc[i, 'ID0_0'] in clientData['CUSTOMERID_transformed']
```

I hope this helps to get you going.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to implement this. Will update you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I got the answer.

```
    if ((only0_0.year[i] - 1) in (clientData['Year'][clientData['CUSTOMERID_transformed'] == only0_0.loc[i, 'ID0_0']].values)):
        only0_0.loc[i,"count"]=1
    else:
        only0_0.loc[i,"count"]=0
```